# IOS: two button control in a UIAlert

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uialertview

I have this code in a IBAction:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"NO!" 
                                                        message:@"danger"
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Annul", nil];

    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
```

Now if I push "OK" it must do a thing and if I push "Annul" it must do another thing. But it must be done inside the IBAction.

Comment: "must be done inside IBAction"..what you mean by that? Why don't you use UIAlertviewDelegate callback clickedButtonAtIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jhaliya's answer is great, except it doesn't address blackguardian's request to run this inside a `IBAction` method. Having an IBAction method block and wait for a response from the UIAlertView is the wrong way to work in CocoaTouch. The `IBAction` should just present the UIAlertView. Then the delegate function in Jhaliya's answer should parse which way to proceed, "OK", or "Annul".  This delegate function can then perform the action (possibly by calling further methods).  CocoaTouch's event handling is not designed for `IBAction` methods to block awaiting further user input.

Think of the chain `IBAction->UIAlertView->alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` as just the `IBAction` when not using an `UIAlertView`, and place your current code in the `IBAction` after this chain.

Answer (score 9):

You need to implement `UiAlertViewDelegate` method.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

So the delegate function should be like below.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
  {
          if(buttonIndex == 0)//OK button pressed
          {

          }
          else if(buttonIndex == 1)//Annul button pressed.
          {

          }
  }
```

Comment: if I use this method delegate have effect inside ibaction?

Comment: I explain my problem: If I push OK the Ib action continue to do its action instead if I press Annul the instruction for the IBAction is "return;"